# Mites on ginger root

Tags: nutrition, microscopy

I was just looking at some mouldy ginger found in the fridge under the microscope and was horrified/delighted to find (what looked to be) mites growing in it. I have searched the web and can only find references to red spider mites which these are certainly not. They were clear white and under 40x zoom about less than a mm across - does anyone know what they could be? Furthermore, what are they feeding on (ginger root is only ~15% carbohydrates - is that enough?) and has a minimal (~1%) amount of protein.

Here is a picture (sorry for the quality but the white thing looks to be a mite).[image: mite]

Comment: LOL "horrified/delighted to find..."

Comment: Pictures? Or, lacking that, can you tell how many body segments they have?

Comment: @Oreotrephes Have fished piece of ginger out of bin and added pic

Comment: Saw a bbc program the other day which talked about mites on cheese, they are (deliberately) all over the rind of some cheeses! I'll try to find it, might (or mite) inspire you to look at other things in your fridge too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this look like the same bug to you ?

[image: bulb mite].

This one is a bulb mite, *Rhizoglyphus robini*, see [here.](http://ipmworld.umn.edu/chapters/straub.htm)

Comment: Yes - I think that's it! I'ts amazing how you can be both fascinated and disgusted at once ;) (It does seem to be harmless though nonetheless)

Comment: I share your feelings :-)

Comment: This is very interesting. We think about microbes (micrometer) and insects (centimeter) as main plant pathogens, but know very few about what fills the gap between these 2 different sizes. At least I learned a lot about medical microbiology, and I know a few plant pathogens as well, but I know nothing about mites. :-)